# How to Show large bitmaps without Resizing like in Gallery

Tags: android, image

I wonder how can android gallery show large images without resizing them. In my application I must have to resize it before displaying else out of memory exception occurs.

Is there any other way to show large images without resizing/scaling down?

One more thing what is the technique behind android gallery zoom? When we zoom the image it gets blur for a while but then become clear in the very next moment.

Further I have googled a lot but couldn't found some appropriate solution.

**Edit**
Currently I'm loading bitmaps like this

```
bitmap = null;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ByteArray,0,ByteArray.length,getBitmapOptions(2));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I got for this was to use WEBVIEW instead of Imageview, its awesome, easy, capable to perform most of the functions by itself..:P

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:minHeight="your_value"
android:minWidth="your_value"
```

for ImageView element in your layout xml file?

Comment: sorry but my problem is lil different. 
I'm performing drawing also over images. I have a custom view extended from imageview.